# How to build chromium as official?

Tags: rendering, chromium

I was trying to build the chromium browser as official but I am not confirmed which files i have to change. On chrome discussion someone told me to just set GYP_DEFINES=buildtype=Official u can see the discussion : https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/chromium-discuss/rendering$20in$20chrome$20slow/chromium-discuss/d4INNgunYtU/9OnP-VMKC10J

I tried a lot editing many files but I haven't get any positive result. PLs help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible to build Chrome as official build. Chrome uses Chromium, but it's a little bit different. For example Chrome has PDF Viewer when Chromium project doesn't contain it. The list of changes between Chromium and Chrome you can find at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ChromiumBrowserVsGoogleChrome

Comment: Someone on the chromium discussion told me that we can build the chromium as official.As I mentioned that in my question description.And I want to build chromium nt the chrome ..